# What status code should be returned, if file, that represents resource is not on the server

Tags: http, http-status-codes

A context:

There is a file on the server that contains some metadata. This metadata is fetched by GET request by client (and used for validation in further flow. In case if there is no file - client & server should skip validation).

Route for this "GET metadata" endpoint is static (e.g. localhost/api/config/metadata).

What status code should I return if file is not present on the server?

This concern appeared because of the statement, that 4xx error are returned if server cannot process request because of some sort of client's error. In our case, client I can't say that client did smth incorrectly.

*my opinion*

I considered that if there is no file, than resource is not present on server and user should get a 404 status code. 
In case I'm missing some point, pls, correct me.

Comment: Where did you get the statement that 4xx signifies a processing error?

Comment: as general overvirew - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400

Comment: This is http status 400, not a blanket 4xx.

Comment: A agree, but isn't there a common rule, that 4xx errors are caused by user?
For example on the same resource (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) it says that 4xx errors are client errors. Isn't it means that these errors caused by user?